# can not use portal template in power apps

Tags: powerapps, powerapps-canvas, powerapps-modeldriven, dynamic365

I want to create a Power Apps model-driven app with Dynamics 365 Finance and Operations. I would like to use portal templates, but I cannot find the option for portal templates, I search about community template, but I did not find any portal templates.

Are there any permission roles that I need to activate, or should I download a package within the Dynamics 365 environment?